# Problem with generator script -- uninitialized constant Rails::Generator::Commands::Base::ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I have an issue with my generator script. Here is the command I am using:

```
ruby script/generate migration add_stuff
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
uninitialized constant Rails::Generator::Commands::Base::ActiveRecord
```

I have tried updating my system, as well as installing/uninstalling my rails application.

I am working on Windows XP, rails version 2.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will see this error if ActiveRecord is disabled. Check if this line is uncommented in config/environment.rb and, if so, try commenting it out:

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer ]
```